# ARM Template / DSC - Deploying 4 Sharepoint VMs - Error copying powershell modules on the VM

Tags: azure, powershell, sharepoint, azure-resource-manager, dsc

I am trying to deploy 4 SharePoint Virtuals Machines (2 App / 2 Web) in an AD Domain Set to Azure using ARM Template and Desired State Configuration (DSC). I use DSC configuration to configure my Sharepoint Vms but as you can imagine, there is a problem...

In my ARM template (JSON), I have following definition of the DSC extension :

```
{
        "name": "ConfiguringSharepoint",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
        "dependsOn": [
            "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/AddSPVMsToAD"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "[variables('configuration').configuringSharepointUrl]",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            },
            "parameters": {
                "spappVMName": {
                    "value": "[parameters('spappVMName')]"
                },
                "sqlVMName": {
                    "value": "[parameters('sqlVMName')]"
                },
                "location": {
                    "value": "[parameters('location')]"
                },
                "spConfigurationModulesURL": {
                    "value": "[variables('configuration').spConfigurationModulesURL]"
                },
                "spConfigurationFunction": {
                    "value": "[variables('configuration').spConfigurationFunction]"
                },
                "domainName": {
                    "value": "[parameters('domainName')]"
                },
                "adminUserName": {
                    "value": "[parameters('adminUserName')]"
                },
                "adminPassword": {
                    "value": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
                },
                "sharePointSetupUserAccountUserName": {
                    "value": "[parameters('sharePointSetupUserAccountUserName')]"
                },
                "sharePointFarmAccountUserName": {
                    "value": "[parameters('sharePointFarmAccountUserName')]"
                },
                "sqlServerServiceAccountUserName": {
                    "value": "[parameters('sqlServerServiceAccountUserName')]"
                },
                "sqlAOAGName": {
                    "value": "[variables('sqlAOAGName')]"
                },
                "administrationContentDatabaseName": {
                    "value": "[variables('administrationContentDatabaseName')]"
                },
                "configDatabaseName": {
                    "value": "[variables('configDatabaseName')]"
                },
                "contentDatabaseName": {
                    "value": "[variables('contentDatabaseName')]"
                },
                "sharepointCAfqdn": {
                    "value": "[variables('sharepointCAfqdn')]"
                },
                "sharePointSetupUserAccountPassword": {
                    "value": "[parameters('sharePointSetupUserAccountPassword')]"
                },
                "sharePointFarmAccountPassword": {
                    "value": "[parameters('sharePointFarmAccountPassword')]"
                },
                "sharePointFarmPassphrasePassword": {
                    "value": "[parameters('sharePointFarmPassphrasePassword')]"
                },
                "sqlServerServiceAccountPassword": {
                    "value": "[parameters('sqlServerServiceAccountPassword')]"
                },
                "spwebVMName": {
                    "value": "[parameters('spwebVMName')]"
                },
                "sharepointFarmName": {
                    "value": "[parameters('sharepointFarmName')]"
                },
                "sharepointWebfqdn": {
                    "value": "[variables('sharepointWebfqdn')]"
                },
                "spSiteTemplateName": {
                    "value": "[parameters('spSiteTemplateName')]"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The "spConfigurationModulesURL" parameter point to Azure blob container which contains a .zip with my 
SharePointConfiguration.ps1. located in the root directory of the ZIP Archive.

The complete URL looks like this : 
https://azuredeploy.blob.core.windows.net/azuredeploy-dsc/SharePointConfiguration.ps1.zip

And the content of the SharePointConfiguration.ps1.zip ZIP Archive : [SharePointConfiguration.ps1.zip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pljfz.png)

On Azure when the extension is running on the first VM (Azure-spapp0), I am getting the following error :

{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.","details":[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"VMExtensionProvisioningError\",\r\n \"message\": \"VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'Microsoft.Powershell.DSC'. Error message: \"The DSC Extension received an incorrect input: An error occurred while executing script or module 'SharePointConfiguration.ps1': The term 'C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.80.0.0\bin\..\DSCWork\SharePointConfiguration.ps1.2\SharePointConfiguration.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again..\nPlease correct the input and retry executing the extension.\".\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}"}]}

So, I analyzed the Azure logs on the VM and I figured out that DSC isn't copying the required powershell modules from the ZIP Archive to "C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\" as expected but instead he's copying the whole unziped Archive "SharePointConfiguration.ps1" and try to install it like a module. So it as obviously failed.

Screen of the Powershell module folder on the Azure-spapp0 VM : [C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOkGq.png)

The Azure logs on the Azure-spapp0 VM (C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.80.0.0) :

```
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:18:08Z] Downloading configuration package
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:18:08Z] Downloading 
https://azuredeploy.blob.core.windows.net/azuredeploy-dsc/SharePointConfiguration.ps1.zip to 
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.80.0.0\bin\..\DSCWork\SharePoint
Configuration.ps1.2\SharePointConfiguration.ps1.zip
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:18:19Z] Extracting SharePointConfiguration.ps1.zip
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:18:19Z] Installing custom DSC resource modules to 
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:18:19Z] Installing custom DSC resource module 
SharePointConfiguration.ps1
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:18:19Z] Copying 
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.80.0.0\DSCWork\SharePointConfigu
ration.ps1.2\SharePointConfiguration.ps1 to C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SharePointConfiguration.ps1 ...
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:18:19Z] Looking for the definition of the configuration
 function.
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:18:19Z] Executing 
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.80.0.0\bin\..\DSCWork\SharePoint
Configuration.ps1.2\SharePointConfiguration.ps1
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:18:19Z] Loading VM agent telemetry assemblies ...
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:18:19Z] [ERROR] while enabling MDS telemetry... [MDS 
Telemetry] C:\WindowsAzure\Packages\WindowsAzureEventSource.dll does not exist 
...
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:18:19Z] [ERROR] An error occurred while executing 
script or module 'SharePointConfiguration.ps1':  The term 
'C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.80.0.0\bin\..\DSCWork\SharePoin
tConfiguration.ps1.2\SharePointConfiguration.ps1' is not recognized as the name
 of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
 the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
```

I got another DSC extension to add my VM to the AD Domain and the modules are correctly copied like this on the same VM :

```
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:15:08Z] Extracting AddSpServersToAD.ps1.zip
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:15:08Z] Installing custom DSC resource modules to 
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:15:08Z] Installing custom DSC resource module 
xActiveDirectory
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:15:08Z] Copying 
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.80.0.0\DSCWork\AddSpServersToAD.
ps1.1\xActiveDirectory to C:\Program 
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\xActiveDirectory ...
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:15:08Z] Installing custom DSC resource module 
xComputerManagement
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:15:08Z] Copying 
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.80.0.0\DSCWork\AddSpServersToAD.
ps1.1\xComputerManagement to C:\Program 
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\xComputerManagement ...
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:15:08Z] Looking for the definition of the configuration
 function.
VERBOSE: [2020-01-29 15:15:08Z] Executing 
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.80.0.0\bin\..\DSCWork\AddSpServe
rsToAD.ps1.1\AddSpServersToAD.ps1
```

So why DSC isn't copying the Powershell modules files for the DSC configuration of SharePoint while he's doing it right for adding the VM to the Domain ?
I think this is why i'm getting this error on Azure but i'm maybe wrong.

I've tried to rename my files, to see if there is any confusion in the paths, but it didn't work.

I hope, I gave you enough information to help me resolve this issue.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I guess its Azure/DSC extension bug but im still investigating it. For me at this time was one time error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @YSDimov, I hope you'll find something interesting. Actually I'm working on it too, but I still didn't achieve to make it work :(